# Problems importing folium into IPython Notebook on Python 3.3

Tags: python, leaflet

I'm getting an error trying to import folium into an IPython notebook running on Python 3.3 in a VM. I've done a pip3 update so it shouldn't be a problem with a stale package...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-af6e4f19ef00> in <module>()
----> 1 import folium

/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/folium/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
----> 2 from folium import Map

ImportError: cannot import name Map
```

Any ideas if this is likely to be a problem with my set up, or an issue with `folium`. There are a couple of other people seem to have had the same issue, but no answers that I can find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a version issue and a pull request has been submitted: https://github.com/wrobstory/folium/pull/21#issuecomment-43231895